# How do I define symbolic variable in a subfunction in matlab? Getting: "Attempt to add "bar" to a static workspace."

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to define a symbolic variable in a sub function foo (see below)

```
function [ ] = test2( )

foo();

     function [] = foo ()
         syms bar;
     end

end
```

I get the following error and am not sure how I can resolve this:

```
EDU>> test2
Error using assignin
Attempt to add "bar" to a static workspace.
 See MATLAB Programming, Restrictions on Assigning to Variables for
 details.

Error in syms (line 66)
        assignin('caller',x,sym(x));

Error in test2/foo (line 6)
        syms bar;

Error in test2 (line 3)
foo();
```

Would appreciate any help to sort out the above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just skip the `syms` function. It uses `assignin` to output the arguments which isn't permitted for nested functions at run time. Try:

```
function [ ] = test2( )

foo();

     function [] = foo ()
         bar = sym('bar');
         disp(bar+bar);
     end

end
```

Output:

```
2*bar
```